# An interview topic: What can go wrong with this code?

Tags: java, spring

A simple Calculator class that's wired up as a Spring bean in a web application:

```
public class Calculator { 
    int result; 

    public int addTwoNumbers(int first, int second) { 
        result = first + second; 
        return result; 
    } 
}
```

What can potentially go wrong with this?

Answer (score 31):

Multi threading problems. By default Spring beans are singletons.

Comment: public class Calculator { 

    public int addTwoNumbers(int first, int second) { 
        int result = first + second; 
        return result; 
    } 
}

Comment: it will fix the class in the scope of my answer

Comment: There's merit in having result as a field, that's how calculators work. Proper fix would be to synchronize access.

Answer (score 13):

Integer overflow is another problem, if this counts.

To solve it, you can return `long` instead:

```
long result;
public long addTwoNumbers(int first, int second)
{
    result = (long)first + second;
    return result;
}
```

Be careful with just saying `result = first + second;`, as the two `int`'s will be added, giving an `int` (which can overflow), which would only then be converted to a `long`.

`result = (long)first + second;` is equivalent to `result = ((long)first) + second;` (not `result = (long)(first + second);`), meaning we convert one of the `int`s to a `long` first, so it would be `long + int`, which gives a `long`.

Comment: public class Calculator { 

    public long addTwoNumbers(int first, int second) { 
        long result = first + second; 
        return result; 
    } 
}

Comment: That will have the same problem - the two int's will be added, giving an int (which can overflow), which would only then be converted to a long. Edited.

Comment: Excellent! I like this. +1

Comment: The problem is far-fetched. What if I want a long calculator? On interview the question was about thread safety.

Comment: @Noofiz It's not far-fetched (if anything, possible arithmetic overflow problems are not given enough attention). I agree that it might not be what the interviewer was looking for, but giving it a brief mention (along with the threading issue) should only help your chances of landing that job.

Answer (score 7):

This class is not Thread safe assuming this is a Spring singleton bean. If two thread call addTwoNumbers there is a chance that the first thread will get the result of the second thread's calculation, so we may get 2 + 2 = 5. If result field is not supposed to be used anywhere else it should be gotten rid of

```
public class Calculator { 
      public int addTwoNumbers(int first, int second) { 
        return first + second; 
     } 
}
```